# operator does not exist: bigint = uuid in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, uuid

I want to use uuid field as my id (primary key) but there is something wrong with it and i can't fix it

this is my model

```py
class Cart(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name='items')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['cart'], ['product']]
```

This Is MY Serializer.py

```py
class CartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['id', 'product', 'quantity']


class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(read_only=True)
    items = CartItemSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['id', 'items']
```

And My Views.py is

```py
class CartViewSet(CreateModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Cart.objects.prefetch_related('items__product').all()
    serializer_class = CartSerializer
```

My database Is postgres Sql

[My Error when I browse my api my guid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO8C9.png)

Comment: 1) Why use a `UUID`? 2) Do not post image for textual information. Copy and paste the error to you question as text. 3) Look at the error message it has the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you create a UUID field `uuid = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=None, editable=False)` first before your initial migration.
2. If you have already done the initial migration, then drop the database and recreate it and don't forget to delete the migration files.
3. Run migrations again and you should be good to go.